# Cryptanalysis of ARX Ciphers

Tags: cryptanalysis, arx

[Rotational Cryptanalysis of ARX](https://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/20041/1/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-642-13858-4_19.pdf) show that rotational probability of an ARX primitive can be computed by $p^q$ where $p$ is rotational probability of modular addition and $q$ is number of modular additions in ARX primitive.
Similarly, [Rotational Cryptanalysis of ARX Revisited](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/095.pdf) extends it to chained additions.

How to calculate rotational probability/ extend above cited probabilities to ARX primitives that employ both modular addition and multiplication?

Is the rotational probability for modular addition and subtraction be same?

Comment: "Is the rotational probability for modular addition and subtraction be same?": remember, $a-b = \overline{ \overline{a} + b }$, and so modular addition and subtraction differ only by some bit complements...